# How ExcelExtractor decides to use comma or dot as thousand separator?

Tags: apache-poi, locale

I have this static method that receives a file path from a `.xls` file and extracts a single `String` out of it. I'm using [POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) to retrieve this data. This is the code:

```
private static String readsIPCASheet() throws Exception {
    String filePath = unzipsIPCAfile();
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(input));
    ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);
    extractor.setFormulasNotResults(true);
    extractor.setIncludeSheetNames(false);
    extractor.setIncludeBlankCells(true);
    String text = extractor.getText();
    extractor.close();
}
```

I discovered that using my local machine (located in Brazil) I receive the following data:

```
198.22  40.27   171.24  568.17  98.22   3,035.71
```

But when I run this code on my VPS (located in US) I receive this:

```
198,22  40,27   171,24  568,17  98,22   3.035,71
```

Using unix `locale`, I got this:

Remote:

```
wildfly@server:~$ locale
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Local:

```
gabriel ~ $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Since I dealing with regex after this piece of code, I prefer to set a standard about this than solving two unnecessary situations. How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apache poi` Excel extractors (`HSSF` as well as `XSSF`) are using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) for formatting numeric values. So `DataFormatter` decides to use comma or dot as thousand separator. At least in the last stable `apache poi` version `3.17`, it does this decision dependent of the [LocaleUtil.getUserLocale()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/LocaleUtil.html#getUserLocale--). See [DataFormatter.java:235ff](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.java?view=markup#l236).

So if you do setting [LocaleUtil.setUserLocale](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/LocaleUtil.html#setUserLocale-java.util.Locale-) before creating the extractor, then this locale will be used to decide to use comma or dot as thousand separator.

Example

```
...
LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(java.util.Locale.US);
ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);
...
```

uses `US` locale in `DataFormatter` and so uses dot as decimal separator and comma as thousand separator.